# $\operatorname{Hom}_B$ of flat modules is flat over $A$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules, flatness

Let $(A, \mathfrak{m}) \rightarrow (B,\mathfrak{n})$ be a local homomorphism of noetherian local rings and let $M$ be a finitely generated $B$-module flat over $A$. Suppose moreover that $B$ is also of finite type and flat over $A$.

**Q:** Is it true that $\operatorname{Hom}_B(M,B)$ is flat over $A$?

I've tried to use the flatness of $M$ and $B$ to show that the natural map $$\mathfrak{m}\otimes_A \operatorname{Hom}_B(M,B) \longrightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_B(M,B)$$ is injective (to apply the Local Criterion for flatness) but I could not prove that neither find a counterexample.

**ADDED:** Here follows an naive idea I had.

Consider the free resolution of $A/\mathfrak{m}$:
$$
\cdots\longrightarrow A^k  \overset{R}{\longrightarrow} A^n  \overset{G}{\longrightarrow} A \longrightarrow A/\mathfrak{m} \longrightarrow 0
$$
where $G= (a_1, \dots, a_n)$ is given by the generators of $\mathfrak{m}$ and $R= (r_{ij})$ is given by the first syzygies. Then we have
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_B(M,B)^k  \overset{R}{\longrightarrow} \operatorname{Hom}_B(M,B)^n  \overset{G}{\longrightarrow} \operatorname{Hom}_B(M,B)
$$
and $\operatorname{Tor}^A_1 \left( A/\mathfrak{m}, \operatorname{Hom}_B(M,B)\right)= \ker G / \operatorname{im} R$. We just need to see if $\ker G \subset \operatorname{im} R$. Let $(f_1, \dots, f_n)\in \ker G$ i.e. $\sum_j a_jf_j =0$. Then for every $x\in M$ we have $\sum_j a_jf_j(x) =0$ and since $B$ is flat there exist $(g_1(x), \cdots, g_k(x)) \in B^k$ such that 
$$
f_i(x) = \sum_j r_{ij}g_j(x)
$$
and we have $g_j \colon M \longrightarrow B$ maps of sets.

The problem is reduced to show whether we can produce $B$-homomorphisms this way.

Note that when $M$ is free (as a $B$-module) then we only need to define $g_j$ on generators but in general it is not true. Also note that the flatness of $M$ was not used so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea:

Since you have the morphism $\alpha:A\rightarrow B$ you have the next isomorphism

$$Hom_{B}(M,Hom_{A}(B,A))\cong Hom_{A}(M,A)$$

With $M$ a $B-$module that can be seen as an $A-$module.

Now we have that $B$ is a finitely generated flat $A$-module where $A$ is a noetherian local ring. It follows that $B$ is a free $A$-module therefore $B\cong\displaystyle\bigoplus_{i\in I}A$ for some finite set $I$.

From this we have that

\begin{eqnarray}
Hom_{B}(M,B)&\cong&Hom_{B}\left(M,\displaystyle\bigoplus_{i\in I}A\right)\\
&\cong&Hom_{B}\left(M,\displaystyle\bigoplus_{i\in I}Hom_{A}(A,A)\right)\\
&\cong& Hom_{B}\left(M,Hom_{A}\left(\displaystyle\bigoplus_{i\in I}A,A\right)\right)\\
&\cong&Hom_{B}(M,Hom_{A}(B,A))\\
&\cong&  Hom_{A}(M,A).
\end{eqnarray}

Since $M$ is a finitely generated $B-$module and $B$ is a free module over $A$ you have that $M$ is a finitely generated $A-$module which is flat as an $A-$module therefore $M$ is a free $A$-module.

It follows that $M\cong\displaystyle\bigoplus_{j\in J}A$  for some finite set $J$.

Thus

$$Hom_{A}(M,A)\cong \displaystyle\bigoplus_{j\in J}A $$

whence it follows that $Hom_{B}(M,B)$ is a free $A-$module and hence it is a flat $A-$module

Comment: This answer seems suspicious to me (though perhaps I am just mistaken). Why should a finite type local extension of local rings be module-finite?

Comment: I read it is f.g. instead of finite type. So in that case I am not sure. The devil is in the details.

Comment: @Liddo Thank you for your effort anyway. I THINK that $M$ and $B$ are both free as $A$-modules by Mittag-Leffler property (http://www.numdam.org/article/CM_1972__24_1_11_0.pdf ). But I don't know if it helps (if it is true).

Comment: Here is an example of a finite type local extension of local rings which is not finite, originally due to [Balarka Sen](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54257789#54257789) in chat: $k[t^2]_{(t^2-1)} \subset k[t]_{(t-1)}$. This answer now needs a good amount of modification in order to be correct. For Alan, I'm not sure about that, but I am still thinking about your larger problem (albeit somewhat slowly).

Comment: Thanks @KReiser. Such examples are easy to construct from geometric insight. Fix a field $k$ and let $A$ be any finite type local $k$-algebra. Now let $B= A[x_1,\cdots, x_n]_\mathfrak{p}$ for some prime $\mathfrak{p}\subset A[x_1,\cdots, x_n]$.

Comment: @AlanMuniz no, that's not correct - more work is required. For a localization map $R\to S^{-1}R$ to be of finite type, we must be able to write every element in $S$ as a product of powers of some finite number of elements of $R$. So even the easiest examples of your method cannot work: set $A=k$, and now consider $k[x]$. $k(x)=k[x]_{(0)}$ is well-known not to be finite type over $k$, and no localization at a maximal ideal works either: $k[x]$ is a PID with infinitely many prime elements, and all but one have to be inverted - this violates the above condition.

Comment: @KReiser Interesting! I did not realize that before. The case that interests me the most is a point  $x\in X \times_k S$ projecting to a point the base $s\in S$ where $X$ and $S$ are schemes of finite type over a alg closed field $k$, $X$ projective/$k$. So I may edit or create a new question.

Comment: If that other scenario is really your interest, I would advise you to ask a new question with the appropriate context - while you've committed the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here, this question is at least interesting to me and I'd like it if you could keep it around so I can see whether I can answer it. (The central issue which makes this question not do what you want is that $X\to Y$ finite type with $x\mapsto y$ does not imply $\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}\to \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ finite type - the correct finiteness hypothesis on local rings would be something like essentially of finite type.)

Comment: @KReiser Thanks. I will keep this question and make another.